# Binary string to decimal conversion

Tags: c++, binary, bit

`C++` has an elegant way of converting an integer to binary string format with `std::bitset< 6 >( 5 )`.

This will write number 5 with 6 bits, so the output will be "000101".

My question is if its possible to convert this back with a similar method, doing the vice versa thing, so putting in the "000101" and getting the output 5.

Comment: [`std::bitset<6>("000101").to_ulong()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong)...?

Comment: tyvm, i misunderstood the documentation... @JHBonarius